# android spinner drop down items not shown

Tags: android, width, spinner, android-spinner, dropdown

I'm trying to show simple spinner

```
    mSpinnerHeaderType = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    String[] items = new String[]{Constants.TYPE_112R, Constants.TYPE_314R};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(mContext, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    mSpinnerHeaderType.setAdapter(adapter);
```

In layout xml

```
<Spinner
         android:id="@+id/spinner"
         android:layout_width="100dp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left"
         android:spinnerMode="dropdown"></Spinner>
```

But when I click on spinner, 
either 1. the dropdown list width is almost zero
    OR 2. there are no itmes in dropdown

I tried, 1. giving spinner width as match_parent in xml layout and 2. using dropDownWith property for spinner etc, but nothing working

See image below:

[image]

What wrong I'm doing?

Comment: you have only two items in array.

Comment: adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); you need not set this line.

Comment: @santoshkumar i have also tried without that line, nothing changes, output is same

Comment: add more item in array and check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this.

```
   mSpinnerHeaderType = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
       String[] items = {Constants.TYPE_112R, Constants.TYPE_314R};
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(mContext, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);
        mSpinnerHeaderType.setAdapter(adapter);
```

xml file

```
<Spinner
         android:id="@+id/spinner"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:spinnerMode="dropdown"></Spinner>
```

Comment: there is no issue in this code may be due to some other reason it does not work.

Comment: try the same whatever i have added.